# Updating an email in a Live Journey - if it's in the Journey more than once, does each need updating?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have some Journeys that contain multiple instances of the same email.

Do I need to update each instance of the common email?  Or do I just need to update it once?

This relates to this SF Help topic - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_update_an_email_in_a_running_journey.htm&type=5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, each email activity needs to be republished to apply any changes. You can also do this is in bulk by going Email Studio > Interactions > Triggered Sends > Journey Builder Sends and locating you journey and version and checking the boxes and pause/publish/Start the triggeredsends

Comment: Thank you.  The Email Studio alternative is much quicker in my case.